# selenium exact match based on text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

If I have some HTML:

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-plotResults-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="50">50</span>
```

And I want to find it using something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "50")]')
```

The problem is that there is `500` somewhere before on the webpage and it's picking up on that, is there way to search for a perfect match to `50`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `contains`, search for a specific `text` value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="50"]')
```

And if you know it will be a span element, you can be a little more specific:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="50"]')
```

Note that your question asks how to find an element by its text value. If possible and would apply to your situation, you should look for a specific class or id, if known and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for it by its absolute Xpath. For that, inspect the page and find the element. Then right-click it and copy its Xpath or full Xpath.

Otherwise you can use the id:

`driver.find_element_by_id("select2-plotResults-container")`

[Here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) is more on locating elements.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
msg_box=driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3u328') and driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-tab = "{}"]'.format('1'))
```